# Finding values of a function

Tags: functions

If $f(x)$ = $x^3 + 1$, how do I find $f(x^2)$ ?

I have the answer sheet, but I would like to see the 'solution' to understand the problem. Thanks and regards,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace $x$ with $x^2$ in the function.

So $f(x^2) = (x^2)^3 + 1$.

Answer (score 1):

If given a function $f(x) = x^3 + 1$,

then for any function $g(x)$, we can compute $f(g(x))$ by replacing every $x$ in $f(x)$ with $g(x)$ instead.  So, in the case of $$f(x) = x^3 + 1 \implies  f(g(x))= [g(x)]^3 + 1$$

Then given $g(x) = x^2$,
$$f(g(x)) = f(x^2) = (x^2)^3 + 1 = x^6 + 1$$